# Find and replace non utf8 character

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I have a process that inserts data into PDFs that eventually loads into a system that gets searched based on that inserted data. The inserted data looks something like:

```
<<
/IBM-ODIndexes
<< /Private
<<
  /DOB (05031983)
  /FULL_NAME (TEST USER)
  /YEAR (2020)
>>
/LastModified(D:20210112201530)
>>
```

However, there are instances where the data in the `FULL_NAME` field contains non UTF8 characters and then users are unable to search the data. Specifically apostrophes come over from Microsoft Word and then gets interpreted like this:

`/FULL_NAME (JERRY OÃ<83>Â¢Ã¢â<80><9a>Â¬Ã¢â<80><9e>Â¢CONNELL)`

In this case I am looking to strip out the apostrophe that is represented as `Ã<83>Â¢Ã¢â<80><9a>Â¬Ã¢â<80><9e>Â¢` and replace it with a white space.

Comment: Give more information on what your INPUT data looks like, is it a set of files? does it contain only the data to insert? Start from `tr -c '\n[:alnum:]/<>():_-' ' ' < inputfile` and find out which characters were incorrectly removed based on your input (remove the `-c` to see only removed characters)

Comment: @Camusensei - the input data are PDFs where we have software scrape that data and save it to flat files to later insert into the data.

Comment: If it's always apostrophes, and always getting represented as `Ã<83>Â¢Ã¢â<80><9a>Â¬Ã¢â<80><9e>Â¢` -- then is there a reason you don't use the obvious kludge, and do a global substitution like `:% s/Ã<83>Â¢Ã¢â<80><9a>Â¬Ã¢â<80><9e>Â¢/ /` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several complexities here, but in general I would say that the only reliable way to deal with it is to figure out the text encoding of the incoming document and *converting* it to the target encoding.

`Ã<83>Â¢Ã¢â<80><9a>Â¬Ã¢â<80><9e>Â¢` is *34* characters (that is, at least 34 bytes), and no single encoding ever used that much space for a single character. What’s probably happening is multiple levels of encoding, such as HTML entities, base64, UTF-8/16/32 or escape characters like `%%` to represent `%` in SQL or `\\` to represent `\` in Bash. Reversing all these levels of encoding manually is going to involve quite a lot of reading the huge docx standard. The simpler alternative is to use a library which can just convert the entire text into a known character encoding for you, at which point you have to do at most a single conversion into UTF-8.

Another argument for this is that the “apostrophe string” does contain otherwise harmless characters like “a” and “e”. Without at least *some* understanding of the encodings you’re unlikely to be able to separate encoded characters from non-encoded ones, which would make the resulting text full of invalid text.